# About Birkhoff averages

Tags: ergodic-theory

I have the following problem

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu, T)$ be a measure-preserving dynamical system, and let $f\in L^1(\mu)$. Let $\tilde{f}(x)$ be the limit of the Birkhoff averages of $f$ (defined almost everywhere). Show that $$\tilde{f}(x)=\lim_{\lambda\to 1^-}(1-\lambda)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\lambda^jf(T^j(x))\quad for\thinspace a.e.\thinspace x.$$

Honestly I don't know how to proceed.

If anyone can give a Hint it will be appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: Are there any other assumptions?  Some assumptions must be made to assume the limits exist.  What does $f \in L^1(\mu)$ mean, particularly with respect to $E[|f(T^j(X))|]$ for each $j$?   It would be easier to prove if you can assume the limits exist and if the $f(T^j(x))$ values are bounded for all $j$ (bounded $f(T^j(x))$ values allows you to neglect the tail of the infinite sum).

Comment: @Michael: no other assumptions are needed - the set-up is the same as for the pointwise ergodic theorem (the limit only exists a.e. though). Hint: write $(1-\lambda)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\lambda^jf(T^j(x))$ as a linear combination of the means $m_n=\frac 1 n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(T^j(x))$, then show this linear combination tends to $\lim_{n\to\infty} m_n$ whenever that limit exists.

Comment: @Dap : Ergodic theorems usually have language of "measure preserving map $T$," which is not assumed in the above question.  Also, it is still unclear what $f \in L^1(\mu)$ means with respect to the operator $T$.  What if hte system is completely deterministic, $x=5$ w.p.1, $f(x)=x$, $T(x)=x^2$? Then $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lambda^j f(T^j(5)) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lambda^j 5^{2^j}$ does not converge.

Comment: @Dap : I see you edited the question to change "measurable dynamical system" (which I would think means any dynamical system with a well defined probability law) to "measure-preserving dynamical system" (which relates to ergodic theory and may be what the asker intends). "Measure preserving" is the kind of "other assumptions" I was seeking in my first comment, so I think we now agree the extra assumption was needed.  However, your edit is "secret" as it gives no comment to me or anyone, and it seems to retroactively change the question to support your prior comment while undermining mine.

Comment: @Michael: sorry, I guess I should have linked to the edit review page. For future reference "measurable dynamical system" is often used as a synonym of "measure-preserving dynamical system".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me add to Dap's hint and Michael's comments that the dynamical system is a distraction in this problem.  The simpler and more general statement is to that Cesàro summability implies Abel summability (with the same value).

Namely, let $a_0,a_1,\ldots$ be a sequence of real numbers and assume that the Cesàro averages $S_n:=\frac{1}{n}(a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1})$ converge to a number $\overline{a}$ as $n\to\infty$.  The claim is that the power series $(1-\lambda)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\lambda^j a_j$ converges to $\overline{a}$ as $\lambda\uparrow 1$.

This can be proven using Dap's hint.  Now from the ergodic theorem, the sequence $f(x), f(T(x)), f(T^2(x)), \ldots$ is almost everywhere Cesàro summable to a function $\tilde{f}(x)$.  Therefore, it is also Abel summable to the same value $\tilde{f}(x)$.

Comment: I think it is worth clarifying that it's really the Cesàro mean and "Abel mean" (not a standard term), not the sum. There is an easy equivalence between means and sums i.e. sequences and series, but it can be a little confusing. By the way, Hardy's "Divergent Series" Section 5.12 has a lovely proof of Cesàro sum =.> Abel sum using a lemma that equivalent divergent series give power series that diverge at the same rate as $x\to 1^-$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some details on importance of the *measure preserving* assumption that Dap added as an edit for the question.

#### The special case of measure-preserving $T$

In general, $f \in L^1(\mu)$ does not imply $f(T) \in L^1(\mu)$. However, it *is* true in the special case when $T$ is *measure-preserving* (so that $\mu(A) = \mu(T^{-1}(A))$ for all measurable sets $A$). If $T$ is measure-preserving  and if $h$ is any measurable and integrable function, it can be shown that: 
$$ \int h(x)d\mu = \int h(T^j(x)) d\mu \quad, \forall j \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\} $$

#### Intuition on weighted averages:

If $f \in L^1(\mu)$ and $T$ is measure-preserving, then there is an $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that: 
$$ \int f(T^j(x)) d\mu = a \quad, \forall j \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\} $$
It follows that if $\{w_j\}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ are any nonnegative weights such that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} w_j = 1$, then 
$$ \int \left[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} w_j f(T^j(x)) \right]d\mu = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} w_j a  = a  $$

where passing the integral through the infinite sum can be formally justified by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem using the integrable bounding function $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} w_j |f(T^j(x))|$.

This holds for any type of weighted average, including a sum like $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(T^j(x))$ or an exponentially weighted average like $(1-\lambda)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \lambda^j f(T^j(x))$. 
Further, since the integral is finite, it follows that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} w_j f(T^j(x))$ is well defined and finite for almost all $x$ (except possibly a set of measure zero).

#### More on the Dap hints

As  Dap mentions, the measure-preserving assumption ensures an ergodic-type  theorem that, for almost all $x$, ensures the sequence $\{m_n\}$ converges to some real number $m$, where both $m_n$ and $m$ can depend on $x$ and where $m_n$ is defined for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ by 
$$ m_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(T^j(x)) $$
Dap’s hint of writing $(1-\lambda) \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \lambda^j f(T^j(x))$ in terms of the $m_n$ values is a good one and you should follow that through.  However, the resulting argument is still non-trivial. It will help to remember that since the values $m_n$ converge, those values are also bounded.  Also, it may help to eventually rewrite the summation in a different order and/or  break it up, if needed, into terms that have one behavior and terms that have another.